# Bootstrap - Logo at top and navbar below logo

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a lightweight responsive website. Bootstrap is the easiest way. 
I found simple themes at startbootstrap.com but I dont want fixed menu at the top. 
I want to put a logo to top and menu below it. When user scrolls down logo will disappear and menu will become fixed to top. 
I can only explain this by examples:

I dont want this: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/

I want nav menu and logo like this: http://webyzona.com//templates/themeforest/globalnews/#

Thanks for help.

Comment: What have you tried? To get help on something like this, we need to see your code.

Comment: Its nice that you know what you want and dont want. sure the company paid plenty of money to get someone to develop that nice navigation

Comment: Put some time and create some code.

Comment: This means you need to put the logo on a different container. But just below the `navbar`

Comment: @GreenFox Above or below?

Comment: thanks a lot but I am a java coder so my css and html code skills are very bad. So I must find a ready to use template. the second link I sended is too complex for me. I must turn the first one to second one (about nav menu)

Comment: My bad was the navbar on the top? or on the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

**About the logo on top and and navbar under it:**

This is a simple as switching the order around in HTML, there is nothing more to it.

**Making navbar slide up**

This can be achieved by using jQuery, the .slideUp() and .slideDown() method to be precise. Or im not sure, but i think you can do it with CSS3.

Source(s):

[JQuery SlideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

[JQuery SlideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

**Using bootstrap**

If you want a lightweight website i wouldnt recommend you bootstrap. Since is has a lot of stuff you will never use. Instead look into SASS and Mediaquery's.

[Media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

[SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com)

After reading your post, honestly i think that you should invest into making a plan for the website and do some research and developement on it. For us to have some source code to juggle with makes it much more easy for us! :)

Comment: thanks a lot but I am a java coder so my css and html code skills are very bad. So I must find a ready to use template.

Answer (score 0):

This just **[DEMO you need to add menu items](http://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/wn2onq2p/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        var $header = $("header"),
            $clone = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("clone"));

        $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            console.log(fromTop);
            $("body").toggleClass("down", (fromTop > 20));
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. is it possible to add a logo above red banner?